# Android camera not closing on click of back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have invoked native camera from my app using intent as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile) );
      startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
```

When i run the application, the native camera is invoked as expected. But when i click the hardware back button to close the camera then nothing happens!

The camera refuses to close and no matter how many times i click the back button. Sometimes i have to restart the device.

I tried the following option:

```
@Override    
protected void onPause() 
{        
    super.onPause();
                stopService(intent);
}
```

But still no success...

However, i have also noticed this strange behavior with my sony device..the code works fine on a samsing tablet..

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Might it be that the intent is being fired as soon as your application is resumed? Can you provide us with some more code?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

I tested it on my device, `Sony Ericsson arc s`. It works and the back button is working.

Comment: the code shared by you is similar to my code. Can you please explain which part you have modified?

Comment: you just need to identify the photo which is a file that take the photo from external storage by `getExternalStorageDirectory()` with the type `jpg`